# Trying to run Plasmati Graduate CV template

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am trying to install this CV [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv).

I have installed the `Fontin` fonts [manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-many-font-files-fast-and-easy) and the `fontspec` package included in `Tex Live`.

However, I am getting the following messages:

[image]
Could you please help? I am here for hours trying to solve.
Thanks!

**EDIT (after Johannes_B's comment):**

*First lines:*

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian
(format=xelatex 2015.10.11)  11 OCT 2015 20:18 entering extended    
mode restricted \write18 enabled.
```

*Last lines:*

```
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n on input li
ne 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n on input l
ine 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)
/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)
/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/it on input 
line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/bx/n on input 
line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)
/bx/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)
/bx/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/LatinModernRoman(0)/bx/it on inpu
t line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 1.
 (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12765 strings out of 493918
 268926 string characters out of 6150562
 297964 words of memory out of 5000000
 16010 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3728 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1144 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,1n,42p,10529b,148s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
```

Comment: My first guess: update your TeX distribution.

Comment: `Tex Live` [installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) today. I didn't use it before.

Comment: Are you sure that you have TeX Live 2015 installed? Not every version of Ubuntu has the latest TeX Live in their repos!

Comment: Run the following code and show us the file list from the end of the log-file, as well as the very first 5 lines.
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is the attached text fine?

Comment: That is not the filelist i wanted, but just as @blue_tiger300 warned, you have quite an old version of TeX Live installed.

Comment: You *could* `remove` tex-live and install a current version using a maintained script: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=23749

Comment: Are there any news here?